The products persist in local storage after being removed
cart.js
import {
  products
} from "../html/products.js";


export const cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart')) || [{}];


let cartHTML = "";
cart.forEach(x => {
  cartHTML += `<div class="product" data-product-id="${x.id}">
        <div class="image">
        <img class="img" src="${x.image}" alt="Product Image">
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <h2>${x.name}</h2>
            <p>Price:Rs.${x.price} </p>
            <p>Quantity:<p id="quantity">${x.quantity}</p></p>
            <button class="update">update</button><button class="delete">delete</button>

            <br><br>
        </div>
        </div>`
});
document.querySelector(".totalHTML").innerHTML = cartHTML;

export function addToCart(event) {
  const ProductId = event.target.closest('.productParent').querySelector('.products').dataset.productId;
  const Product = products.find(product => product.id === ProductId);

  const dropDownElement = event.target.closest('.content').querySelector('.select');
  let selectedValue = Number(dropDownElement.value);

  const matchingProduct = cart.find(x => x.id === Product.id)
  if (matchingProduct) {
    document.querySelector(`.product[data-product-id="${ProductId}"] #quantity`) += selectedValue;
  } else if (Product) {
    Product.quantity = selectedValue;
    cart.push(Product);
    console.log("pushed");
  }
  localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart));
};

const deleteBTNs = document.querySelectorAll('.delete');
deleteBTNs.forEach((x => {
  x.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    const nearProduct = e.target.closest('.product')
    const ProductId = nearProduct.dataset.productId;
    console.log(nearProduct.dataset)
    const updatedCart = cart.filter(x => x.id !== ProductId)
    console.log(updatedCart)
    // localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(updatedCart))
    nearProduct.remove();
    localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(updatedCart));
    // console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart')))
  })
}));

script.js(main script file)
import {products} from"../html/products.js";
import {addToCart, toDelete, } from"../html/cart.js";


let productsHTML="";
products.forEach(x => {
productsHTML+=`
    <div class=productParent><div class="products" data-product-id="${x.id}">

    <div class="image">
        <img class="img"src="${x.image}" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="content">
    <div class="productName">${x.name}</div>
    <div class="productPrice">Rs.${x.price}</div>
    <select name="number"  class="select" >
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
    </select>
    <button class="addtocart" >Add To Cart</button>
    </div>
</div>
</div>`
});
document.querySelector(".totalHTML").innerHTML=productsHTML;



const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.addtocart');

buttons.forEach(btn => {
    btn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {

        addToCart(e);
        
        //for cart Quantity 
        const selectElement = e.target.closest('.content').querySelector('.select');
        let selectedValue = Number(selectElement.value);
        cartMath(selectedValue);
    });
});

let cartQuantity=0;
export function cartMath(x){
    cartQuantity+=x;
    document.getElementById("cartQuantity").innerHTML=cartQuantity;
};

homepage.html(main html)
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/homepage.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="nav"><a href="../html/cartpage.html">Cart</a><span id="cartQuantity">00</span>
    </div>
        <div class="totalHTML">
            <!-- html that is now in script.js-->
        </div>
</body>

<script src="script.js" type="module"></script>
<script src="products.js" type="module"></script>
<script src="cart.js" type="module"></script>


</html>

cartpage.html(cart html)
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/cartstyle.css">
    <title>Add to Cart</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="totalHTML">
</div>

<div class="cart-summary">
    <h2>Cart Summary</h2>
    <p>Total Quantity: <span id="total-quantity">0</span></p>
    <p>Total Sum: Rs. <span id="total-sum">0</span></p>
    <p>Delivery Charge: Rs. 250</p>
    <p>Dashain Offer: Rs. -50</p>
    <h3>Total Payable: Rs. <span id="total-payable">0</span></h3>
    <button class="buynow">Buy Now</button>
</div>

</body>
<script src="cart.js" type="module"></script>
</html>

products.js(the storing of items)
export const products=[
    {
        id:"1",
        name:"shoe",
        image:"images/products/knit-athletic-sneakers-gray.jpg",
        price:1200,
        quantity:1,
    },
    {
        id:"2",
        name:"shirt",
        image:"images/products/adults-plain-cotton-tshirt-2-pack-teal.jpg",
        price:1000,
        quantity:1,
    }, 
    {
        id:"3",
        name:"Sandals",
        image:"images/products/women-beach-sandals.jpg",
        price:200,
        quantity:1,
    },
    {
        id:"4",
        name:"Dinner Plate",
        image:"images/products/6-piece-white-dinner-plate-set.jpg",
        price:2750,
        quantity:1,
    },
];

I tried putting the localStorage here and there but didn't work.
I got a suggestion to rerender but I couldn't do it.
Another thing I think would work is after clicking delete, update the HTML in cart.js file itself.
Please make the deleted product not appear after deleting and reloading the carthtml page.

Not related to the problem, but why do you initialize cart with an empty object in the array, instead of an empty array?

The delete button removes the item from localStorage, but it doesn't remove it from cart. So the next time you do localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart));, the item will be put back into local storage.

Instead of assigning the filtered cart to updatedCart, assign it to cart.

@Barmar it doesnt matter if both of them are empty.
and it also doesnt matter cause that is a variable so it wont work if i filter the cart and assign it to cart again it says Cannot access 'cart' before initialization.

@Barmar i deleted the object in array but didnt work this image shows the console log=> https://imgur.com/a/wsXFmZJ

The code in that screenshot declares a local variable named cart, which shadows the global variable.

I added
cart = updatedCart;

inside the forEach:
 deleteBTNs.forEach((x => {...

and changed const cart to let cart.

Why not just cart = cart.filter(...)? Why do you need updatedCart?
